# Android: Reading different .txt for different classes

Tags: java, android, assets

Hi all I know it could be an easy question but i cannot solve the following issue. I have different .txt and I have different classes. I need to read a specific txt for each class. For that purpose I have a class which is used for reading the different txts but I need in each class to read the appropiate .txt.
Here is my example:
Here I read the txt and I say the txt I want to read:

```
public void currentQuestion(Context context, int cat) {
    category = cat;



    String questionFile = "";
```

Then in each class I need to read the especific txt.
For example in class car it would be String questionFile = "cars.txt"; and so on.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `getClass().getSimpleName()` where ever you want to use the class name in your application

Answer (score 1):

Well if your text files have the same name as your class name then you could use something like:

```
String filename = this.getClass().getSimpleName()+".txt"
```